# Angular 5 - Replacement for json().token in HttpClient?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular5

With Angular 5 deprecating Http and HttpModule in favor of HttpClient and HttpClientModule, I haven't been able to figure out how to pass session tokens around similar to how I used to. For example, this is how I used to do it:

```
loginUser(loginData) {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', loginData).subscribe(res => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.json().token);
    })
  }
```

Now that json is the assumed default, how would I do something similar to "res.json().token"? The closest I have found is to use "JSON.stringify", but the problem is it passes the entire json object into the header, not just the token itself. ie;

```
loginUser(loginData) {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', loginData).subscribe(res => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res));
    })
  }
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('token', res.token)` ?

Comment: just omit `.json()` part

Comment: I tried omitting .json() early on, but it errors with a "Property token does not exist on type 'Object'."

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right, @AJT_82. Bravo and thanks! I was actually just explicitly adding an interface inline like so:

loginUser(loginData) {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', loginData).subscribe((res: {token: string}) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
    })
  }