# How to Logout in Angular / Spring by POST

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to logout by Angular using POST method, here is my code:

```
  logout() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8181/user/logout';
    const xToken = localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken');
    const basicHeader = 'Basic ' + localStorage.getItem('credentials');
    const headers = new Headers({
      'x-auth-token': xToken,
      'Authorization': basicHeader
    });
    // return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }); // This will work
    return this.http.post(url, { headers: headers }); // This will generate error
  }
```

And this my backend:

```
@RequestMapping("/user/logout")
public ResponseEntity<String> logout(){
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Logout Successfully!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The weird thing is the code above work with `this.http.get` but will generate below error with `this.http.post`. And here is error with `this.http.post`:

```
POST http://localhost:8181/user/logout 401
```

If I modify code using HttpClient, like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    let url = "http://localhost:8181/token";
    let encodedCredentials = btoa(username + ":" + password);// encode in base64 to send a token
    let basicHeader = "Basic " + encodedCredentials;
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': basicHeader
    })
    // send credential method when login component
    return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }); // Error at this line
  }

  checkSession() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8181/checkSession';
    const xToken = localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken');
    const basicHeader = 'Basic ' + localStorage.getItem('credentials');
    const headers = new Headers({
      'x-auth-token': xToken,
      'Authorization': basicHeader
    });
    return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }); // Error at this line
  }

  logout() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8181/user/logout';
    const xToken = localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken');
    const basicHeader = 'Basic ' + localStorage.getItem('credentials');
    const headers = new Headers({
      'x-auth-token': xToken,
      'Authorization': basicHeader
    });

    return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }); // Error at this line
  }
}
```

Then I get error message:

```
(property) headers?: HttpHeaders | {
    [header: string]: string | string[];
}
Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
  Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
    Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.ts(2322)
http.d.ts(1086, 9): The expected type comes from property 'headers' which is declared here on type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'
```

at line `return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers });`

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post your `component` code? Where your calling a `LoginService`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `headers` like this:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('x-auth-token', xToken).set('Authorization', basicHeader);
```

and then,

```
return this.http.post(url, null, headers );
```

Pass `null` as it accepts `body` as in the second parameter.

**Using HttpClient**:

`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

`constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }`

in **app.module.ts:**

`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

and in @NgModule:
`imports: [ HttpClientModule ]`

Comment: I've tried, but got error `Type 'HttpHeaders' is missing the following properties from type 'Headers': forEach, values, toJSON, entries, mayBeSetNormalizedNamets(2739)`. If I change to `return this.http.post(url, headers, null );`, I got the same error

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using `HttpClientModule`

Comment: `this.http` --> Please show what your consctructor `(http:HttpClientModule )`

Comment: @mrSmith91 post exists in HttpClientModule, may be there is some syntax issue

Comment: I didn't lie you. I paste error message for you: `Property 'post' does not exist on type 'HttpClientModule'.ts(2339)`

Comment: it should be `constructor(private http: HttpClient)`; That issue comes when you try `(http:HttpClientModule )` Please show constructor

Comment: So what is the difference between Http and HttpClient? I used private http: Http in my constructor, but now I need to define another private http:HttpClient for using POST method? Why can't I get both POST and GET method from http or HttpClient

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? HttpModule got obsolete from Angular5. You have to use HttpClientModule from Angular 5 +

Comment: Oh my Lord! I'm using Angular 8. Currently I'm using `Http `, and it works perfectly, but I can't use `Http ` with POST method. Do you have any idea to use both POST and GET by `http` or `HttpClient` ? Because using both seem verbose.

Comment: Use both with HttpClient

Comment: And import `HttpClient` from what? `@angular/common/http` or `@angular/common/http/http` or `selenium-webdriver/http`? I tried all, but get error at line `return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers });`, error message: `Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
  Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
    Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Wait a minute. I am updating the use in the answer

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I still get problem. I updated my post with full code when change to `HttpClient `. Please view and help me!

Comment: `let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('x-auth-token', xToken).set('Authorization', basicHeader);`

`this.http.get(url, headers );`

Comment: Great, but I got this error `localStorage.setItem('xAuthToken', res.json().token);` because of `Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.`? I changed to `res.toString()`, but won't work.

Comment: `res = [object Object]`. Nothing to see

Comment: `console.log(typeof res)`. If it is string then ` console.log(JSON.Parse(res)` else expand it and share the screenshot

Comment: I tried this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484875/angular-5-replacement-for-json-token-in-httpclient?noredirect=1&lq=1`, but it seems OK. Now I will check other things. Thanks for ur help

Comment: You are welcome @mrSmith91. If you can somehow show me `res`, I can help u. This is a really small thing

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, by default `@RequestMapping("/user/logout")` will accept only `GET` requests. You have to set the method explicitly

```
@RequestMapping("/user/logout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> logout(){
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Logout Successfully!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Or use `@PostMapping`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient){}
logout()
{
    const url = 'http://localhost:8181/user/logout';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('x-auth-token', localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken'));

    return this.http.post(url, '' ,{headers: headers, responseType: 'text'})};
```

In Spring, my recommendation would be to use `@PostMapping` or `@DeleteMapping` annotation instead of `@RequestMapping`. The reason for using `ResponseType` as 'text' is because you are providing `ResponseEntity<>` as of `String` type and by default Angular perceives the response as JSON.

Further, remember to use `localStorage.removeItem('xAuthToken');` in the response when subscribing to that observable & also unsubscribe that observable in `ngOnDestroy()` lifecycle.

Comment: So what is the difference between `Http` and `HttpClient`? I used `private http: Http` in my constructor, but now I need to define another `private http:HttpClient` for using POST method? Why can't I get both POST and GET method from `http` or `HttpClient`

Comment: `http` module is a deprecated module and `HttpClient` module is a improved replacement of `Http`module. You must use httpClient for all the types of request whether it is GET, POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE. HttpClient Module was introduced in 4.3 and has many benefits such as progress event, interceptors for middleware logic. The conclusion is use `HttpClient` instead of `Http` as it is deprecated by the Angular Team

Comment: I modified to use `HttpClient ` but got other problem. I already updated my code on my post. Please view and help me if possible.

Comment: Headers is a part of http module and it is also deprecated. So, now you need to set headers in this way:new HttpHeaders().set('name', value)' For Example, in sendCredential() you have to use `const headers = new HttpHeaders().set( 'Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization', basicHeader); return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers });`

Comment: Great, but I got this error `localStorage.setItem('xAuthToken', res.json().token);` because of `Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.`? I changed to `res.toString()`, but won't work.

Comment: `res.json()` would not be applicable as Angular by default perceives json response. So the best way is: 
`this.loginService.sendCredential(username,password)
  .subscribe(
 (res:any) => {
   localStorage.setItem('xAuthToken', res.token )
 }
);`